# An exercise about zerodivisors

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

If $A$ is a commutative ring with unity, $f\in A$ and $x\in SpecA$,  with the notation $f(x)$ I mean the coset $x+f\in A/x$. Now look at this exercise:

> Prove that a nonzero element $f\in A$ is a zerodivisor if and only if there exists a decomposition $SpecA=X\cup X'$ where $X\subseteq$ $SpecA$ and $X'\subsetneq Spec A$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$.

One direction is easy: ($\Rightarrow$) If $f$ is a zerodivisor, it's not invertible, so $f$ is contained in a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. We have that $SpecA= V(f)\cup D(f)$ where $D(f)\neq Spec A$ because $\mathfrak m\notin D(f)$.

I have problems to show that the other direction. Any hint?

Comment: Maybe, but the text of the exercise is that I've written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice for you that you have problems showing the other direction, since it is completely false!

Take for example $A=\mathbb Z$ and $f=2$:
Clearly $f=2$ is not a zero divisor.  However  $\text {Spec}(A)$ can be written as $\text {Spec}(A)=X\cup X'$, with $X=V(2)=\{(2)\}$ , $X'=\text {Spec}(A)\setminus V(2)\subsetneq \text {Spec}(A)$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$ .

Comment: It is an exercise from Shafarevich's book (volume 2, number 1.2)! Many thanks.

Comment: Dear Galoisfan: Shafarevich is a great geometer but I think he learned pre-Grothendieck algebraic geometry. If I remember correctly, there are other inaccuracies about schemes in his book. Anyway, I just checked my copy of his book and I notice that I wrote (probably long ago) in pencil that this exercise is false.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the standard definition of irreducibility is that the components $X,X'$ in the decomposition are closed - this, I think, is what Georges  was pointing out.

The direction you were looking for can be solved using the following idea from Hartshorne:

Given two closed sets $X \cup X' = \operatorname{Spec} A$, taking complements gives us two open sets $U,U'$ such that $U \cap U' = \varnothing$. Now we can glue together a zero function on one with a nonzero function on the other, which gives us zerodivisors in $A$.

Comment: Dear Zvi, the exercise does not mention irreducibility. Could you please give a  precise statement of what you think is true?

Comment: Dear Georges, Good point! I was reading into the statement for rings the scheme-theoretic statement that $X$ is integral iff it is reduced and irreducible. Translated into ring language, I suppose that would mean that a decomposition of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ into two proper subsets, closed in the Zariski topology, means that there is a local zerodivisor.

Comment: Also, it is  false  that if you have two regular functions on two disjoint open subsets  of a scheme you can glue them to   to a regular function on the scheme.

Comment: Yes - I see that this only gives a local zerodivisor. I translated the question into scheme language in my head too hastily!

Comment: No harm done, Zvi, don't worry!